# How to use the Material Design Theme on pre Android 5.0 Devices

Tags: android, material-design, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm starting an app that should use the material design theme.

But the minSDK for that project is api level 15.

How do I set up the app to use as much Material Design as possible on lower versions on Android?

Comment: You can find it here, backport: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the guide that was recommended by Dodge.

Add

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
```

to your dependencies.

Now put a style into your values folder:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
             which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
             colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

    </style>

</resources>
```

Now you have to add it to your application in your manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

This setup inherits from a NoActionBar theme to make it possible to also use the compat Toolbar.